# Can you convert a 2-d array to a hashtable?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, winforms, hashtable

I've been looking for this but am unable to find anyone trying to do this.  Is it possible to convert a 2 dimensional array to a hashtable?

Comment: Would a Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue) be also acceptable ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an straight method to do that. But you can always loop through the array and add the values to a hash table. (Assuming first dimension elements are unique)

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length(FirstDimension); i++)
     hastable.add(arr[i,0], arr[i,1])
```

Not exactly VB, or C#, But I hope you get the idea.

In C# you could create an Extension method to do this if, you use it quite extensively, not sure about VB though.